# como puedo pasar el string de una lista a una lista de verdad

Tags: python-3.7

Por ejemplo
string = "[[1, ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]"
y quiero pasar eso a lista.
lista = [[1, ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]

Comment: Tu pregunta es de muy mala calidad, al realizar una pregunta adjunta en código que tienes hasta el momento para que sea mas facil ayudarte y no dar la impresion de que no has hecho nada.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el modulo "ast" de python, el cual te permite convertir estructuras como (strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None) para ser interpretadas y obtener su respectivo tipo de instancia.

```
import ast
cadena_lista = u'[ "A","B","C" , " D"]'
lista = ast.literal_eval(cadena_lista)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/AwareCoolDevelopers

Documentacion: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval